# (React.js) Bubble sort issue

Tags: reactjs, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort, selection-sort

I'm creating a sorting algorithm visualiser. When I click "generate", an array of unsorted integers is created and rendered to the screen. When I click the "Bubble sort" button, I want the entire array to be sorted in one go, but whats actually happening is bubble sort stops after each pass and I have to click "Bubble sort" multiple times to sort the array (see my image links for reference). I have also implemented a selection sort algorithm and I am having the same problem. How can I fix this? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

[generates an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If4lq.png)
[after bubble sort is clicked once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEEPo.png)

this pattern of continues until the array is sorted. I have to continuously click the "bubble sort" button to sort the array.
Heres my code for the bubble sort algorithm.

```
//============ bubble sorts array when button is clicked
  bubbleSort() {
    const arr = this.state.array;
    const n = arr.length;
    
    for(let i=n-1; i>0; i--) {
      for(let j=0; j<i; j++) {
        setTimeout(() => { // setTimeout for each swap so we can see the swap happening
          if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
              let temp = arr[j];
              arr[j] = arr[j+1];
              arr[j+1] = temp;
              this.setState({ swaps: this.state.swaps + 1 }); // each swap increment swaps state by 1
          }
          this.setState({ comparisons: this.state.comparisons + 1 }) // each comparison increment comparisons state by 1
        }, i * 10); // timeout is i * 10 millisecconds 
      }
    }
    this.setState({ array: arr });
  }
```

This is my render function where I am returning JSX.
[render function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFUIF.png)

Comment: You're mutating state. Never do that in React

Comment: I'm relatively new to React, could you tell me how I can avoid mutating state please?